# Accessing test context data in custom cucumber formatter/listener

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am creating some kind of custom reporting with cucumber with custom listener/formatter. but I am unable to add some data from test context to my report.

I know we share data/state between steps using cucumber-picocontainer, but my question is **how can I access test context data from the custom listener/formatter that i am writing**?

Cucumber-Java : 5.2.0

**Update:** Adding more details. is there a way i can use use context object in the custom listener/plugin. i would like to `context.setFailMessage("");` from the custom listener.

[image]

Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: If you have already written something then please share the code as well. So that we can try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create custom reporting in cucumber, you have to follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** Implement ConcurrentEventListener interface

```
  public class DesktopStepDisplayer implements ConcurrentEventListener
```

**Step 2:** Add the implementation in EventHandler as show below

```
private EventHandler<TestStepStarted> eventHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() 
{
    public void receive(TestStepStarted event) 
    {
        if(event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
        {
            String message = ((PickleStepTestStep)event.getTestStep()).getStep().getText();
        }       
};


public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, eventHandler);
    
}
```

**Step 3:** Set the event publisher

```
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, eventHandler);
    
}
```

**Entire Script:**

```
public class DesktopStepDisplayer implements ConcurrentEventListener {

    private EventHandler<TestStepStarted> eventHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() 
    {
        public void receive(TestStepStarted event) 
        {
            if(event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
            {
                String message = ((PickleStepTestStep)event.getTestStep()).getStep().getText();
            }       
    };


    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, eventHandler);
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: This would be an answer on how to write custom listener/plugin with cucumber. but  my question is different. I wanted to use the context object in the custom listener.

Comment: Could you please share the code of your runner as well.